# Why is the for loop not running inside my if statement? Java

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop

My problem is that when I run the code the if statement is run but then the for-loop is bypassed. I am new to this and this is by first post. All help is welcome.

```
if (tMenuChoice == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("How many teams are there going to be?");
            int tNumberOfTeams = tKeyboard.nextInt();

            // This is where the code stops running. The for loop is not read but bypassed.

            for (int i = 1; i == tNumberOfTeams;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Team " + i + "'s name?");
                String tNameOfTeam = tKeyboard.nextLine();
                String [] tTeamArray = new String[i]; 
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please review how `for` loops work: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html.

Comment: Agree. You know it's the for loop that is wrong, so you should study the tutorials or your book on for loops, and you'll see right away your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i == tNumberOfTeams;i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < tNumberOfTeams;i++)
```

The problems were that it would get false for the test condition on the first run and never do that iteration. Also, since you were writing to an array, you needed to start with 0.

Comment: @arshajii OP is using an array.

Comment: The code runs now but skips over the part where the user needs to input the name of the team. How do i get it to stop and prompt the user before it begins to run again?

Comment: @user2540126 What is tKeyboard? A Scanner? Please read up on Scanner.

Comment: Yes tKeyboard is connected to the object scanner.

Comment: You should try using a debugger to help you. Your IDE most likely provides one.

Comment: I am using the debugger but after looking through documents on scanner I am still unable to figure out why scanner skips over the input. Also I cannot figure out how to prevent the loop from skipping over the user input.

Comment: @user2540126 - The `Scanner` is most likely reading the rest of the *previous* line; i.e. the whitespace / newline character after the last digit of the number.  You need to call `nextLine()` to skip to the start of the next line of input ... before reading the player name.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the line:

```
int tNumberOfTeams = tKeyboard.nextInt();
```

Make sure the value being assigned to tNumberOfTeams is greater than 1 and also, like the commenter above stated, for loops should never contain == in the continue condition (2nd param). If this is intended, I'd suggest either another if statement or some other code block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the condition statement of your for loop:
(int i = 1; i == tNumberOfTeams;i++)

You are first initializing the variable i to 1
Then you have the condition - The loop will only be executed if this condition evaluates to true. The condition is i == tNumberOfTeams. Unless the number of teams is equal to 1 (which is the value currently stored in i), the loop will not be executed at all.

What you probably want to do is say i<=tNumberOfTeams, so that the loop will keep running as long as that statement is true.